# Rhetorical device for sentence structure imitating meaning

Tags: single-word-requests, poetry, rhetorical-devices

I am trying to find the specific rhetorical device which means that the structure of the sentence I’m writing about imitates the meaning. In this particular case the writer using enjambement to convey an idea of movement

example:

Godiva, I unpeel/
Dead hands, dead stringencies

(I want to argue that the unpeeling is mimicked in the sentence structure ie the enjambement)

Comment: Unless you can offer several other (and hopefully more obvious) examples, my opinion is that such a term would not have been considered useful and thus is unlikely to exist. There _are_ contrivances where layout is chosen to mimic the silhouette of a tree, butterfly etc.

Comment: A poem with more stark line breaks would make your case stronger. In the Brideshead series, the star recalls a jarring "conversation of broken sentences"—and that scene's endless choppy dialog matches the heartbreak of its meaning.

Comment: Yes you’re right it isn’t that obvious from these lines. I wanted to add it in with an argument from later lines where the “I” is separated by enjambement from the verb such as:     

And now I/ Foam to wheat, a glitter of seas. 

Another example:                                     

And I/ Am the arrow, // The dew that flies/ suicidal,

Comment: Sorry about the formatting this is my first post from my phone. So basically my overall argument is about the metaphorical dissipation of the self (which is encapsulated in the “unpeeling”) and to add to my point I want to talk about how the author is also “unpeeling” through the formatting of the lines

Comment: Perhaps we need a term that defines an onomatopoeic sentence. But onomatopoeic seems in dictionaries only to be applicable to words. I can suggest no equivalent for sentences.